Is there a source out there which works out a Hartman-Grobman-type theorem on a manifold?
My general goal is to understand more aspects of dynamical systems in the framework and language and differential geometry, and while for most things I can make out some sources which do that, I cant really find any source on a Hartman-Grobman type theorem on a general manifold.
Is there some problem with my goal? Like do we have a negative result in that domain or something? It seems like a natural thing to think about.

It's a local theorem, so it should hold on manifolds too. (Just work in some coordinate chart around the equilibrium point, and then everything looks like in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

I am are of that, but I still have found noone actually writing it down, which is not the case for most other theorems in the general theory i can think of.

But, of course, it is a purely local result. For manifolds, see for instance Ch. 2, Theorem 4.1 in
Palis, Jacob jun.; de Melo, Welington, Geometric theory of dynamical systems. An introduction. Transl. from the Portuguese by A. K. Manning, New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XII, 198 p., 114 ill.  (1982). ZBL0491.58001.
I have read this book when I was a student and liked it quite a bit.

This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much. How on earth has this book not popped up in my dozens of searches? It seems like the exact thing I wanted. Thanks alot
